# "Bacteria don't have membrane-bound organelles." Are sulfur bacteria or Cyanobacteria exceptions?

Tags: cell-biology, bacteriology, organelle

Can bacteria have membrane-bound organelles?

I read this many textbooks:

> Bacteria cells are simple cells that do not contain a nucleus or other membrane-bound organelles. However, they do contain other cellular structures that aid with their life processes.

Or [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ck12.org/biology/prokaryotic-and-eukaryotic-cells/lesson/Prokaryotic-and-Eukaryotic-Cells-MS-LS/&ved=2ahUKEwjF79zu14XsAhWR2KQKHU_PA40QFjAEegQIDBAU&usg=AOvVaw0rzAaRl0CGJ3TGWuHNPq1E):

> Prokaryotic cells (Figure below) are usually smaller and simpler than eukaryotic cells. They do not have a nucleus or other membrane-bound organelles. In prokaryotic cells, the DNA, or genetic material, forms a single large circle that coils up on itself

Are sulfur bacteria or Cyanobacteria exceptions?

Sulfur bacteria because they have big vacuoles. (Vacuoles do have membrane, don't they? Or maybe something is different about prokaryotic vacuoles that I don't know?)

> A [vacuole](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ck12.org/biology/prokaryotic-and-eukaryotic-cells/lesson/Prokaryotic-and-Eukaryotic-Cells-MS-LS/&ved=2ahUKEwjF79zu14XsAhWR2KQKHU_PA40QFjAEegQIDBAU&usg=AOvVaw0rzAaRl0CGJ3TGWuHNPq1E) is a membrane-bound organelle which is present in plant and fungal cells and some protist, animal and **bacterial cells**. (1)

And

Cyanobacteria because they have gas vesicles. (These vesicles are membranous, aren't they?)

[image]

---

(1): Schulz-Vogt HN (2006). "Vacuoles". Inclusions in Prokaryotes. Microbiology Monographs. 1. pp. 295–298.